# Overriding abstract methods in Java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, events, user-interface

Here is a class View of the MVC paradigm, the class consist of 2 `JDialogs`, to be opened on click of `JMenuItem` - `addEvent` and `editEvent`.

```
 public class EventView extends javax.swing.JFrame {



 private javax.swing.JDialog addDialog;
private javax.swing.JDialog editDialog;

private EventModel model;

     /** Constructor */
    public EventView(EventModel model) {
        initComponents();
        this.model = model;
        updateEventTable();       
    }

   public void addEventListener(ActionListener al) {
        addEventButton.addActionListener(al);
    }

  /* public void clearListener(ActionListener cl) {
        clearEventButton.addActionListener(cl);
    }*/

   public void addDialog(ActionListener ae) {
        addEvent.addActionListener(ae);

    }
   public void editDialog(ActionListener ee) {
        editEvent.addActionListener(ee);
    }

}
```

The controller class handles the user interaction with listeners.

```
public class EventController implements ActionListener {

//... The Controller needs to interact with both the Model and View.
private EventModel model;
private EventView view;


/** Constructor */
public EventController(EventModel model, EventView v){

    model = new EventModel();
    view = v;
    //... Add listeners to the view.
    view.addEventListener(new addEventListener());
    //view.clearListener(new clearEventListener());
    view.addDialog(new addDialogListener());
    view.editDialog(new editDialogListener());
}

class addEventListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = "";
        String date;
        String start="";
        String end="";
        String venue="";
        String details="";
        String opportunities="";
        String moreOppor="";

        try {
            name = view.getEventName();
            date = view.eventDate().toString();
            start = view.startTime();
            end = view.endTime();
            venue = view.locationWhere();
            details = view.getDetails();
            opportunities = view.getOpportunities();
            moreOppor = view.getMore();
            model.addEvent(name,date,start,venue,details,opportunities,moreOppor,end);    
            view.showSuccess("Event Added!");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            view.showError(ex);
        }
    }
}


class addDialogListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("");

    }
}
class editDialogListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I have two question in relation to this module:

1. `EventController` is showing an error that it is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed when I believe I did. Correct me if im wrong. I do have an additional JMenuItem called `deleteEvent` but I havent touched that yet. Working on NetbeansIDE F.Y.I
2. I would like to replace the lines `System.out.println("");` with something that will allow me to display the dialog `addDialog` of the view class but I cannot access the component. how to do this? I've tried `view.` but it doesnt show up allow for `setVisible(true)` .

Comment: _the class consist of 2 JDialogs_ I must be somehow blind because I see absolutely no JDIalog

Comment: Where do you think EventController is overriding actionPerformed? EventController appears to consist of two fields, a constructor, and three inner classes - no methods at all.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your compiler is quite right:  `EventController` does not declare a `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method. It does have two inner classes that have the method, though, but that doesn't count.

The way you have named your class, `addEventListener`, suggests that you really meant to call the method `addEventListener` instead of declare a class, but no definite suggestion can be given based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

1) You forgot to implement the actionPerformed() method in the EventController Class.

2) You should set the view as an argument of addDialogListener and editDialogListener.
Something like :

```
public class addDialogListener implements ActionListener {

    private EventView view;

    public addDialogListener(EventView view){
       this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       view.doWhatever();
    }
}
```

And then :

```
view.addDialog(new addDialogListener(view));
```

Comment: @Jaylo isit just the word class? I dont want to add `Private EventView view` again, its already there. can i remove the word class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EventController {

}
```

instead of

```
public class EventController implements ActionListener {

}
```